# Keep ViewModel instance on DialogService

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Prism's `IDialogService.ShowDialog` method creates a new instance of the target viewmodel every time. If possible, can I reuse thesame view model instance? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify if you use C# VB, WPF or Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: ops. I use **WPF**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your dialog view model as singleton to the container in the bootstrapper, e.g. for Unity.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<MyDialogViewModel>();
```

You can also register an instance that you created yourself as instance.

```
var myDialogViewModel = new MyDialogViewModel(...);
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(typeof(MyDialogViewModel), myDialogViewModel);
```

Then the `IDialogService` will resolve the same view model instance each time. You *still have to register the dialog*, so the `ViewModelLocator` can indentify the view model type for a view.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<MyDialogView, MyDialogViewModel>();
```

Alternatively you can register your dialog view like this an set `AutoWireViewModel` to `True`.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<MyDialogView>();
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyViews.MyDialogView"
             ...
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

Comment: RegisterSingleton..! I try this. Thanks.